# How to count how many times a line of code is executed in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

How could I run a simple diagnostic to check how many times a particular line of code is executed (passed by) in Chrome Dev Tools? Obviously without counting it myself with a debugging breakpoint and without writing any redundant code inside the codebase.

I want to do it on a regular basis, that is - I do something on the interface to call for a `for` (f.ex) cycle and I want to see imediately how many times a particular line was executed, then press again and see a new result again (maybe a reset inbetween could be tolerated)

Comment: Maybe with [console.count()](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-reference#count) ? I don't know exactly if this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`console.count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/count), it will log how many times it was called with a given label:

```
console.count('Some Identifier')
```

If you don't want your log filled up with "foo: 19" and just want a total instead, you could create your own `count` function that only returns the total when requested:

```js
var counter = (function() {
  var counters = {};

  return {
    count: function(label) {
      counters[label] = counters[label] ? counters[label] + 1 : 1;
      return this;
    },
    total: function(label) {
      return +counters[label];
    }
  }
})();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
  counter.count('bar'); 
}

console.log("bar called", counter.total('bar'), "times");
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do this with some Chrome Dev Tools extension? that is, without inserting code manually. Would probably be convenient.

Comment: console.count is the built-in, I just sometimes find the output to be a bit much when I only really care about the total

Comment: But you still have to insert console.count into the code, I mean - is there a way to do it with GUI? Like with breakpoints